# Constructor is already defined Duplication errors within swings

Tags: java

I want to declare two...its easy I know

1. fetching values inside a program
2. fetching value form the other Jframe

---

```
public Decode(String key){
    keyValue = key.getBytes();  
}

public Decode(String para){
    initComponents();
    emessage.setText(para);     
}
```

Comment: you can't have two constructors (or methods either) with identical signatures

Comment: `signatures` referes to the parameter

Comment: If you write `new Decode("string")` in your code, how will the compiler know which constructor you are trying to call?

Comment: @notyou that's nonsense.

Comment: @notyou I assumed as much, but I'm pretty sure there is a chance the OP would think you meant it